# Primefaces 6.1 SelectCheckboxMenu - show more column on the data panel

Tags: primefaces

Using Primefaces-6.1/JSF2.0

I have a selectCheckboxMenu working properly, but it just shows one column on the data panel. 
If i add p:column inside selectCheckboxMenu , it does not make any difference. The first column is taken from the selectItems itemValue attribute.

How can i make p:columns to work ?

Below is my Code

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="multipleInst" value="#{publishquestbean.selectedInstitutions}" 
                                                label="Institutions" multiple="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
                                                panelStyle="width:380px" style="width:290px" 
                                                converter="instConverter" converterMessage="unable to convert" var="in" >
                                                    <f:selectItems value="#{publishquestbean.institutionsList}" var="inst" itemLabel="#{inst.instName}" 
                                                        itemValue="#{inst}"/>

                                                    <p:column>
                                                        <h:outputText value="#{in.instName}" />
                                                    </p:column>

                                                    <p:column>
                                                        <h:outputText value="#{in.instId}" />
                                                    </p:column>   
                                               </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

[image]

Comment: Where in the PrimeFaces documentation and/or showcase do you see this is (or should be) supported?

Comment: I dont see it mentioned in the primefaces document, but i felt it will be supported as it is supported by selectOneMenu

Comment: Then it looks your assumption/hope is unfortunately not correct (it is not supported)

Comment: Is this a right candidate for a feature request ?

Comment: Yesm might be. You can even download the source, make the changes and create a pull request. Should not be to difficult